# How to I change the selected color of an Flutter Button

Tags: flutter, web, state, selected

example my code

```dart
 backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
            if (isDisabled) {
              return const FMThemeColor().strong_bt_04;
            } else {
              if (isSelected) {
                return const FMThemeColor().strong_bt_03;
              } else {
                if (states.contains(MaterialState.hovered)) {
                  return const FMThemeColor().strong_bt_02;
                } else {
                  return const FMThemeColor().strong_bt_01;
                }
              }
            }
          }),
```

I found out that there were more conditions.

how to use

> states.contains(MaterialState.selected

This is an example provided by Darts.

```dart
DataTable(
  dataRowColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color?>((Set<MaterialState> states) {
    if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected))
      return Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary.withOpacity(0.08);
    return null;  // Use the default value.
  }),
)
```

But I don't know from this alone.

how to use selected states?

only flutter web project...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
DataTable(
  dataRowColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color?>((Set<MaterialState> states) {
    var defaultColor = Colors.red;
    if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected))
      defaultColor = Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary.withOpacity(0.08);
    return defaultColor;  // Use the default value.
  }),
)
```

Comment: thank you but not working state.....